# Wordpress on localhost (MAMP): site loads text only, all links broken

Tags: wordpress, localhost, mamp

I'm attempting to run a wordpress site at localhost:8888/wordpress/. I can get the site to load text only, but all the links are broken and point to an address like this: localhost:8888/wordpress/localhost:8888/checkout/. In wp-config.php, DB_HOST is localhost. In the database, siteurl and home in wp_options is localhost:8888. What might be the issue?

edit: The repository that contains the wordpress install and the database file is [here](https://github.com/inspireui/mstore).

Comment: You'll want to visit `/wp-admin/options-permalink.php` to get WordPress to write it's rules in the `.htaccess` file at the root of your installation. Also, it should be `http://localhost:8888`, not just `localhost:8888` Have you considered pointing an alias url to your wordpress install with your hosts-file?

Comment: If your WordPress site is in `/wordpress/`, shouldn't `siteurl` and `home` point to `http://localhost:8888/wordpress` too?